# groupby apply operation of all the other keys

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Given a pandas dataframe `df` I can do `df.groupby('Age').apply(lambda x: x['ReadingAbility'].mean())` in order to get the average reading ability for each age.

Now suppose I want the average reading ability for all the ages except `age=k`

I can do:

```
mu_other_ages = {}
for age in df['Age'].unique():
 mu_other_ages[age] = df[df['Age'] != age]['ReadingAbility'].mean()
```

This is somehow the opposite of groupby + apply.
Is there any shortcut to achieve the same result more efficiently ?

See the following example:

```
In [52]: d = pd.DataFrame([[1,10], [2,4],[1, 9], [2,3]], columns=['Age', 'ReadingAbility'])                                                                                                                        

In [53]:                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [53]: d                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[53]:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   Age  ReadingAbility                                                                                                                                                                                             
0    1              10                                                                                                                                                                                             
1    2               4                                                                                                                                                                                             
2    1               9                                                                                                                                                                                             
3    2               3                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [54]: d.groupby('Age').apply(lambda x: x['ReadingAbility'].mean())                                                                                                                                              
Out[54]:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Age                                                                                                                                                                                                                
1    9.5                                                                                                                                                                                                           
2    3.5                                                                                                                                                                                                           
dtype: float64
```

In the cases there are only 2 different Age values tahtn the results should just be inverted as: `2=9.5` and `1=3.5`  while for more classes the value for `Age=k` should be : `df[df['Age'] != k]['ReadingAbility'].mean()`

Just to clarify the expected result for this example is: `2=9.5 and 1=3.5`

Comment: Very fast solution was added, you can check it.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
a = (d.groupby('Age')
      .apply(lambda x: d.loc[d['Age']!=x['Age'].iat[0], 'ReadingAbility'].mean()))

print (a)
Age
1    3.5
2    9.5
dtype: float64
```

Another, very fast solution is aggregate `sum` and `size` for each group and then subtract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) sum of both columns. Last divide:

```
np.random.seed(45)
d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 2)), columns=['Age', 'ReadingAbility']) 
print (d)
   Age  ReadingAbility
0    3               0
1    5               3
2    4               9
3    8               1
4    5               9
5    6               8
6    7               8
7    5               2
8    8               1
9    6               4
```

---

```
a = (d.groupby('Age')
      .apply(lambda x: d.loc[d['Age']!=x['Age'].iat[0], 'ReadingAbility'].mean()))

print (a)
Age
3    5.000000
4    4.000000
5    4.428571
6    4.125000
7    4.111111
8    5.375000
```

---

```
c = d.groupby('Age')['ReadingAbility'].agg(['size','sum'])
print (c)
     size  sum
Age           
3       1    0
4       1    9
5       3   14
6       2   12
7       1    8
8       2    2

e = c.rsub(c.sum())
e = e['sum'] / e['size']
print (e)
Age
3    5.000000
4    4.000000
5    4.428571
6    4.125000
7    4.111111
8    5.375000
dtype: float64
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(45)
N = 100000
d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=(N, 2)), columns=['Age', 'ReadingAbility']) 
#print (d)


In [30]: %timeit (d.groupby('Age').apply(lambda x: d.loc[d['Age']!=x['Age'].iat[0], 'ReadingAbility'].mean()))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.27 s per loop


In [31]: %%timeit
    ...: c = d.groupby('Age')['ReadingAbility'].agg(['size','sum'])
    ...: #print (c)
    ...: e = c.sub(c.sum())
    ...: e = e['sum'] / e['size']
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.28 ms per loop
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is working. Can you check the example?]\

Comment: thanks this is working. But I think it is still very inefficient. I need to try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
d.groupby("Age")['ReadingAbility'].mean()
```

gets you the mean for each group. You can filter out, say `Age = 1`, by adding an query like

```
d.groupby("Age")['ReadingAbility'].mean().reset_index().query("Age != 1")
```

or

```
d.groupby("Age")['ReadingAbility'].mean().select(lambda x: x != 1, axis=0)
```

Alternatively, as Merkle Daamgard points out, you filter out the values you don't need first and then do `groupby` and `mean`.

```
d.query("Age != 1").groupby("Age")['ReadingAbility'].mean()
d.loc[d.Age != 1].groupby("Age")['ReadingAbility'].mean()
d.where(d.Age != 1).groupby("Age")['ReadingAbility'].mean()
```

See [`GroupBy.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with that

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,10], [2,4],[1, 9], [2,3]], columns=['Age', 'ReadingAbility'])
res = df.loc[df['Age'] != 1].groupby('Age').apply(lambda x: x['ReadingAbility'].mean())
print res
```

Which returns :

> Age : 
>   2 3.5